# what character set i should use to use 'ă' character in android

Tags: android

In my android code i have a line like this:

```
> x.charAt(i + 2) == 'ă'
```

when i build android studio(i'm using android studio 2.3.1) show me an error

```
Error:(23, 51) error: unclosed character literal
Error:(23, 53) error: illegal character: '\u0083'
```

i know that i get this error because i'm using wrong charset for android studio but i can't make it right. I have tried using "utf-8", 'ISO-8859-1' charset (set encoding in build.grade file) but they didn't work. I also try show hidden character if it have any in 'ă' but i didn't found any. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use unicode

```
x.charAt(i + 2) == '\u0103'
```

Comment: am i have another choice ? because '\u0103' look unfamiliar. i want to use 'ă' so i can know what character i'm using

Comment: I would just add a comment afterwards specifying the character. Maybe you can assign the char to a ă-variable. I've never used it that way. 

But it's nothing strange to do as this answer says. I would even say that's standard.

Comment: Maybe you are new to asking questions on SO, but it's always nice to accept an answer if you find that it solves your issue.